# Problem - Mesh won't move with armature

Tags: rigging, armature

I'm new to blender.

[image]

I am creating this batman sculpture, and wanted to pose him before going further with the sculpt. I created the armature, then selected the mesh, shift selected the armature, then hit ctrl+P and deformed with automatic weights. I then applied an "armature" modifier to the mesh, and selected the armature object.

However, when I select the armature and go to pose mode, moving the bones does not cause the mesh to move along with them. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, especially because I have done this exact same process once before, and the character mesh moves with the armature.

If anyone could please help me out, that'd me amazing!

Comment: what do you mean when you say that you applied an armature modifier? Once you've parented it creates an Armature modifier but you're not supposed to click the Apply button if this is what you mean. If this is not your problem it can be others like flipped normals or else. Maybe share your file (modify it a bit if you don't want it to be stolen)? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I didn't apply the armature modifier. I had actually looked back at my other working project and saw that there was an armature modifier, so I went and added one to the batman mesh to see if it would solve the problem. I didn't know that the modifier appeared naturally once I parented the armature to the mesh. Either way, it didn't solve anything. ---- I hope noone steals this, but I'm pretty desperate at this point. The file was too large for blend-exchange.com, so I uploaded to my google drive: https://drive.google.com/open?id=15SlZknhTK-zb2H-LCrfdRtvfj6z9YtCq

Comment: Ok so maybe share your file   ;)

Comment: I accidentally hit enter while I was writing the response, was about to share the file. ;P

Comment: The mesh is super-heavy, I don't know if that's the problem, but do you have any good reason not to retopologize it to a low-poly version? It would make the things much easier...

Comment: I know it's heavy, but I'm not finished sculpting, so I'll need the topology to continue... I think I should have posed him much earlier :/

Comment: I would say continue the sculpt, once you're good retopologize to create a low-poly version, bake the normals, rig the low-poly... but maybe someone has a better idea  ;)

Comment: You were right! It was the mesh density! Thank you so much for your help, I'm truly greatful! - I applied a decimate modifier set to collapse at a ratio of 0.2. That took my face count down from 2.2 mil to around 400k. Then I parented the mesh to the armature, and it now moves perfectly! In order to keep the detail, I'm going to pose it while it is low poly, then I'll paint over the details with a high resolution simplify brush in sculpt mode!

Comment: also when you parent the mesh to the armature make sure you've applied the mesh scale and that there is no flipped normals